# Override OSX press and hold accent picker in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, unicode

If you press and hold a key in OSX you get a popup where you can choose different characters.
I've written a little webtool: http://kasperpeulen.github.io/PressAndHold/ that does the exact same thing, but I've added many mathematical symbols to the popups. 
Now I want to override the native OSX tool. What I've tried is:

```
$('input').on('keydown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/nggnjo5a/2/

In Firefox, this does override the native OSX tool. In chrome and safari, it sadly doesn't. Is there any other way to make sure the native OSX app is disabled on my website ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had some luck with turning a `type="text"` field into a `type="password"` field and back again very quickly. I noticed that holding a key down in a password field doesn't trigger the accent popup, and wanted to take advantage of this behavior. This trick doesn't work 100% of the time, and it's an ugly hack -- but its better than nothing. Below is the full code I'm using. I run this on the input field's first focus event.

```
this.disableAccentPopup = function(_input, callback){       
    var last_key_down   = false; // last key pressed
    var last_key_count  = 0; // number of keydown events for last key pressed
    var keys_down       = {}; // all keys being held down

    var input = _input.cloneNode(true); // We will swap this with the original input on first focus
    input.type = "password"; // Password fields don't suffer from accent UI
    input.value = ''; // Empty this so we don't see the password bullets
    input.focus();

    // Right before focus...
    _input.addEventListener("focus", function(e){
        // This setTimeout is needed so we can get the proper selectionStart and selectionEnd values
        setTimeout(function(){
            var t = _input.value;
            var s = _input.selectionStart;
            var e = _input.selectionEnd;
            _input.parentNode.replaceChild(input, _input);
            input.focus();
            // This setTimeout is needed to set the input type w/o breaking the input's behavior
            setTimeout(function(){
                input.value = t;

                input.type = 'input';

                input.setSelectionRange(s, e);
                if (callback) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        callback(input);
                    }, 0);
                }
            }, 0);
        }, 0);
    });

    input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
        keys_down[util.keyIdentifierToKeyCode(e)] = true;
        if (!e.metaKey && e.keyIdentifier.substr(0,2) == "U+") {
            if (last_key_down && last_key_count >= 1) {
                // if this is not the first keydown event for this char,
                // we can safely set the type to input

                input.type = 'input';

                if (last_key_down == util.keyIdentifierToKeyCode(e)) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    last_key_count = 0;
                }
            }
            last_key_down = util.keyIdentifierToKeyCode(e);
            last_key_count++;
        }
    });

    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
        delete keys_down[util.keyIdentifierToKeyCode(e)];
        if (!e.metaKey) {
            // if _all_ keys are up
            if (Object.keys(keys_down).length == 0) {
                last_key_down = false;
                last_key_count = 0;
            }
        }
    });
}
```